# Await.result(...) difference between a fatal Error and Exception treatment in Scala 2.10

Tags: scala, error-handling

Why does `Await.result(f, t)` will re-throw an Exception raised by f, whereas it won't re-throw a fatal Error?

Is it a bug or an intended behavior?

The following REPL sequence reproduces the behavior:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

scala> import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent._

scala> val ec = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global
ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor = scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl@2d2217da

scala> Await.result(Future{throw new RuntimeException()}(ec), Duration.Inf)
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:15)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:15)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$3.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)


scala> Await.result(Future{throw new LinkageError()}(ec), Duration.Inf)
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
    at $line28.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:15)
    at $line28.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:15)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$3.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
    (hanging - needs ctrl-c)
```

The difference between the 2 executions is that the first one will terminate with the execution, and the second one will print the stacktrace and then hang, waiting forever (not sure for what though).

Edit1: replaced `NotImplementedError` by `LinkageError` as the `NotImplementedError` behavior was modified in 2.11.1 whereas `LinkageError` stayed the same.

Edit2: added "fatal" to describe an Error in the question.

Comment: It rethrows both, as your example shows...

Comment: It doesn't actually. The printed stacktrace comes from the future execution, not the Await.result() terminating with an exception. The `(hanging - needs ctrl-c)` was supposed to say exactly that. I'll edit the question to be more explicit.

Comment: I got different behavior inside my REPL, with 2.11. Are you still using 2.10?

Comment: Yes (in the title), that might be a 2.10 specific issue alright.

Comment: A bit of context for the original error I came across. The original error was a LinkageError. It is usually caught by the compilation process, but in my case it happened at runtime. This was because the IDEA Scala plugin didn't update a particular dependency. Not exactly a critical error in my case, but still a strange behavior in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `scala.util.NonFatal` (which is used in the implementation of `Future`) does not match `NotImplementedError`, causing it to be treated as fatal. In 2.11 this was changed, and `NotImplementedError` is no longer fatal. See [this commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/68f62d7e9c200034bd42ffaf795b57fb379d9d38).

Comment: This answers correctly for the particular example I've shown. But now if you look at other errors, the ones that are still fatal in 2.11.1, the question remains. Why is `Await.result(...)` hanging on these? I'll edit the question to use an example that was not modified in 2.11.1 and also using the fatal/non fatal terminology to be more consistent with what's in the Scala source.